# How to check for attachment when sending an email?

Tags: vba, outlook, email-attachments

I've come across macros that check whether any items are attached when you use the word 'attachment' (or any other word you desire) in your email, e.g. the following:

```vb
Public Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim vList As Variant
    Dim answer As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    
    vList = Array("attached", "attachment")
    
    If Item.Attachments.Count = 0 Then
        For i = 0 To UBound(vList)
            If InStr(1, LCase(Item.Body), LCase(vList(i)), vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
                answer = MsgBox("There's no attachment, send anayway?", vbYesNo)
                If answer = vbNo Then Cancel = True
                Exit Sub
            End If
        Next i
    End If
    
End Sub
```

I've only seen macros that check whether the `Item.Body` contains one of the specified words. When responding to an email, `Item.Body` is not just the new text, but also the previous text to which I am responding.
This is a problem, as many clients have the word 'attachment' in their disclaimer. As a result, I often get the warning that there is no attachment at unnecessary moments.

I tried different properties of the `Item` object.

It seems to me there is no way to select only the newest typed text.

Comment: I'd get a count on the ItemLoad(ByVal Item As Object) event, then if the difference is >0 then alert.

Comment: Change the specified word to something common- like **`see attached file`** or **`file attached`** look for multiple words

Comment: @Nathan_Sav, what difference do you mean?

Comment: @Om3r, that does not solve my problem. If I am responding to a message in which someone wrote those words, I will still incorrectly get the warning....

Comment: difference means the end number - start number, so if you check on itemLoad as a public var, then check your count-the start count if its greater than 0

Answer (score 2):

```
Private WithEvents OUT As Outlook.Application

Private lngAttachmentsOnOpen

Private Sub OUT_ItemLoad(ByVal Item As Object)
    lngAttachmentsOnOpen = AttachmentMentionedXTimes(item.body)      '   <---- count here
End Sub

Private Sub OUT_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)

Dim lngAttachmentsOnSend As Long

lngAttachmentsOnSend = AttachmentMentionedXTimes(item.body)'   <--- count here
If lngAttachmentsOnSend > lngAttachmentsOnOpen Then
    MsgBox "This code has been done for me due to my idleness :)"
End If

End Sub

Function AttachmentMentionedXTimes(ByVal strInput As String) As Integer

Dim a() As String

On Error GoTo eHandle

a = Split(strInput, "attachment", , vbTextCompare)

AttachmentMentionedXTimes = UBound(a)

Exit Function

eHandle:

    AttachmentMentionedXTimes = 0

End Function
```

Comment: Could you clarify? You say 'count here', but to me it seems that nowhere you're checking whether words like 'attached' are mentioned, which was my original issue..

Comment: You already have the code for that.  This is to check on open and check on send, if one is greater, then attachment is in the reply.

Comment: But my question is not how to check whether an attachment is present. It is how to properly check whether words like 'attach' or 'attachment' are written in the reply. You say _you already have the code for that_, so please reread my original question, because I do not. So again, I fail to see how your answer resolves that issue and I ask you to clarify.

Comment: What is it you don't get, on opening the email, as in reading it, you do your count, but store to a variable accesable when you reply, so when you open, say you "have please see attachment" your count would be 1, but if the reply was "please see attached corrections", your count would be 2, so 2-1 is >0 hence the word attachment.  The code in your post shows how to detect the presence of the word.  If you haven't cracked it, nor understood me in nearly 2 weeks, i'd leave it :) all the best

Comment: What I don't get, is why you keep talking about counting attachments when that is not what I am after. Again, you say _The code in your post shows how to detect the presence of the word_, that is *not true*. It doesn't work properly and my question is how to fix it.

Comment: "However, I've only seen macros that check whether the Item.Body contains one of the specified words. Apparently, when responding to an email, Item.Body is not just the new email I am typing, but also the previous mail to which I am responding. For me, this is somewhat of a problem, as many of the clients I correspond with have the word 'attachment' in their disclaimer. As a result, I often get the warning that there's no attachment at unnecessary moments.  Does anyone know how to solve this?"

Comment: My answer isn't to count the number of attachments, it's to solve the actual question, you need to reword, if the real question is how to count for instances of a word in text.  My answer is to use your instr code on load to count the existing word attachment, then the same, on send, if the send is greater, then there should be an attachment

Comment: _However, I've only seen macros that check whether the Item.Body contains one of the specified words. Apparently, when responding to an email, Item.Body is not just the new email I am typing, but also the previous mail to which I am responding. It seems to me there is no proper way to select only the newest typed text._  Maybe you should reread instead.

Comment: YES, SO CHECK WHEN YOU OPEN IT, THEN WHEN YOU SEND IT!  AS MY CODE, WITH YOUR CODE INSTR DOES!

Comment: Again, that is not what I am after. I understand your code works, but it is not what I am asking.

Answer (score 2):

Most of the time the first instance of "From: " will be the start of the previous message.

```
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)

    Dim vList As Variant
    Dim answer As Integer
    Dim i As Integer

    Dim newMsg As String
    Dim prevMsgStart As Long

    prevMsgStart = InStr(Item.body, "From: ")

    If prevMsgStart = 0 Then
        newMsg = Item.body
    Else
        newMsg = Left(Item.body, prevMsgStart - 1)
    End If

    vList = Array("attached", "attachment")

    If Item.Attachments.count = 0 Then
        For i = 0 To UBound(vList)
            If InStr(1, LCase(newMsg), LCase(vList(i)), vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
                answer = MsgBox("There's no attachment, send anayway?", vbYesNo)
                If answer = vbNo Then Cancel = True
                Exit Sub
            End If
        Next i
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Yes I was aware af that. But that doesn't work 100% of the time. No disrespect, but I am not looking for workarounds, but for a proper solution.