# My code for a Outlook 2016 attachment reminder doesn't display the correct dialog box

Tags: outlook, attachment

When I use this code:

```
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)
Dim retMB As Variant
Dim strBody As String
Dim iIndex As Long

On Error GoTo handleError

iIndex = InStr(Item.Body, "attach", "attachment")

If iIndex > 0 And Item.Attachments.Count = 1 Then
retMB = MsgBox("Forgot attachment?" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Continue?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo + vbDefaultButton2 + vbMsgBoxSetForeground)

If retMB = vbNo Then Cancel = True

End If

handleError:
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
MsgBox "Sending with no attachments!" & Err.Description, vbExclamation, "ERROR!!!"
End If

End Sub
```

I want to get the "Forgot attachment?" dialog box with the message. Except I only get the "Sending with no attachments!" dialog box. Why doesn't the reminder dialog appear when the email doesn't have an attachment?

Comment: Have you tried to debug the code by running it under the debugger line-by-line? Just try to set a breakpoint on the line of the beginning of the `ItemSend` event handler.

Comment: In general do not put in an error handler until a perfect test item runs. Remove `On Error GoTo handleError` to see the error.

Comment: The error handling appears to be unnecessary. Consider removing all associated code.

Comment: Thanks you all. 
I got rid of `On Error GoTo` and all associated code, and the box already appears, but I had to edit the `iIndex = InStr(Item.Body, "attach", "attachment")` to `iIndex = InStr(Item.Body, "attach")` and it works.
Is there any way to add a list to `iIndex = InStr(Item.Body, "attach")`?

Thanks in advantage.

Comment: "attach" should find "attachment" so your new code is sufficient. If you meant to use "attach**ed**" https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40934390/how-to-check-for-attachment-when-sending-an-email

Answer (score 0):

Your check must be `Item.Attachments.Count = 0`.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I've tried that. I changed to 1 because already have 1 attachment (my signature).

Comment: Get rid of the `On Error GoTo ` statement to fugure out which lines raises the exception/